# php variable scope if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

This is a server side script in PHP. I'm new to PHP. I'm unable to find out why the variables $n,$g and $d don't get modified even if the condition in the *if statement* is true. Global declaration has no effect either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>IFRAME</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    extract($_GET);
    $n="";$d="";$g="";
    if(strcmp($usn,"1se501"))
    {
       global $n,$d,$g;
       $n="bob";
       $d='cse';
       $g='8.8';
    }
    echo "parent.updateRes('$n','$d','$g');";

?>
</script>
<h2>Server done...</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you remove `global` from the `if` scope?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Thanks for suggesting. However the problem turned out to be something else. The page was getting cached in the browser. So, changes in my code were not reflected

Comment: simple rule: disable all caching when developing websites (both memory and disk). You can do that in Firefox easily by going to `about:config`, search for `cache` and disable them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page was getting cached. Hence, changes in my code were not reflected. There's no problem with the code.